# Разместить названия на карте

Tags: python, matplotlib, карты

Хотел разместить названия для точек, которые помещаю на карту, но Python ругается на `labels=names` такой ошибкой:

> AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'labels'

Подскажите, как с этим лучше справиться.

```py
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lat = [52.0084760338068,
       51.98767080903053,
       51.98608445003629,
       52.01591497287154,
       52.01788103207946]
lon = [105.3697749786079,
       105.32037447206676,
       105.32151457853615,
       105.37850498221815,
       105.393730038777]
names = ['ИСТОЧНИК2', 'ЛУНКА', 'ЛУНКА 0', 'ЛУНКА 1', 'ЛУНКА 4']

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=51.94, urcrnrlat=52.10,
            llcrnrlon=105.25, urcrnrlon=105.45, resolution='f')
figsize(10,15)
 
x, y = m(lon, lat)
 
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='gray', lake_color='white')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(51.94, 52.10, .04),labels=[1, 0, 0, 0], fontsize=14)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(105.25, 105.45, .1),labels=[0, 0, 0, 1], fontsize=14)
 
m.scatter(x, y, 20, marker='o', color='k', labels=names)
plt.title("Location of the measurement points", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Что у вас за функция figsize?

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot scatter не имеет аргумента labels. читайте про annotate.